# Cloud9 bottle Web Server, accessed externally

Tags: webserver, bottle, cloud9-ide

I create a Web Server in python using bottle library. Its works fine and run in https://c9.io. I want access this web service externally. 
I´m using host=os.environ['IP'] and port=os.environ['PORT'] to capture the port and ip environment variable.
How can I do it?

Comment: Obs.: I tried use http://project.user.c9.io and work fine if logged, but if not, doesn't! My idea is publish this ws for everyone...tnks

Comment: I received this comment from c9 support team "... We still not support always on workspaces (it will be a premium feature in the next future) ...". So, in this moment I'm creating new GAE supported application based in a cloned workspace (git://github.com/fjakobs/cloud9-gae-template.git).

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do is to replace your host as **0.0.0.0** instead of **localhost**. This will redirect you to your cloud9's localhost. For example, I'm running my app as:

```
bottle.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8082)
```

You can access the server from a new tab after running your server.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am facing with the same problem and my solution was to start the app like this:

```
python myapp.py $IP $PORT
```

And inside the main module used entrypont2 to map those arguments to variable and use it for run bottle:

```
from bottle import run
from entrypoint2 import entrypoint

#...

@entrypoint
def main(ip, port):
   run(server='gevent', host=ip, port=port, debug=True)
```

Then I can reach it from web browser using url like this:

```
http://<workspace>.<user>.c9.io/
```